# How to change application language without restart/closing app?

Tags: iphone, localization

I have implemented language change after restarting my app but my question is can I change my application language without restarting/closing it?

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: You should use the default localazion iOS offers, this way the app will look at the system language and select the correct language that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using the base functionalities of iOS, i.e. localization. What you can do is localizing your app in different languages, and let the iOS itself chose the right language to display when the application starts.

This way, if a user uses the iDevice in English, he/she will see your app in English (if you supported it as a localized language), if he/she uses the iDevice in French, he/she will see your app in French (again, if supported).

The official Apple page about [Internationalization and Localization](http://developer.apple.com/internationalization/) (also called i18n and l10n), can be of great help.

Comment: thanks i followed as you said and implemented ... its working great